# Criptografia de url

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho um metodo de *EnviarEmail* 
que gera um link através de requisição HTTP, que enviará para o e-mail do usuário para realização de troca.
Porém para testes deixei fixo nessa URL o ID do usuário, mas por motivos de segurança tenho que criptografar o mesmo.
Como realizar esse procedimento ?

Segue código

Metodo ConfirmarEnvio

```
  public IActionResult ConfirmarEnvio(Clientes objLogin)
        {
            try
            {
                var link = HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
                Email objEmail = new Email(_config);
                objEmail.CliCodigo = objLogin.CliCodigo;
                objEmail.CliEmail = objLogin.CliEmail;
                objEmail.link = link;
                objEmail.EnviarEmail();
                return View("Login");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Parte do metodo que gera o link:

```
 //From Address  
                string FromAddress = _config.GetValue<string>("From");
                string FromAdressTitle = "TesteEnvio";
                //To Address  
                string ToAddress = CliEmail;
                string ToAdressTitle = "Microsoft ASP.NET Core";
                string Subject = "Redefinição de senha";//Assunto,
                StringBuilder BodyContent = new StringBuilder();
                BodyContent.Append  ("Prezado(a)  para redefinir sua senha, por favor clique no link abaixo.");
                BodyContent.Append  ("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append  ("Link: http://" + link + "/Accounts/RedefinicaoSenha?id=" + CliCodigo +"");
```

E-mail recebido porém com o ID visivél:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só por curiosidade, por que criptografar o ID do usuário vai trazer alguma segurança?

Comment: Pois se eu colar essa URL desta forma, irá abrir a view de alteração de senha e, assim qualquer pessoa poderia alterar a senha, sem quaisquer impedimento. Veja, para o usuário chegar nesse ponto de alteração é preciso que seja feito uma solicitação na tela de Login, onde automaticamente ira carregar uma modal já com o e-mail referente ao ID do usuário travado, assim impedimento que seja feito alteração de e-mail por terceiros.

Comment: Cara ao meu ver a criptografia não vai te ajudar muito nesse caso. Qualquer pessoa com este link, mesmo que criptografado, no mundo inteiro poderia acessar sua aplicação. Acho que você poderia trabalhar com um link temporário sabe? 10 minutos ou menos. Crie uma chave e envie essa chave que pode ser em md5 ou sha1, etc. Envie a chave no link do e-mail e relacione esta chave ao usuário que vai trocar a senha. Entende? Ponha um tempo curto porém suficiente. Desta forma, sua segurança vai estar um pouco melhor que apenas criptografar o id do usuário.

Comment: @IgorCarreiro E você acha que criptografar o ID do usuário é a melhor solução pra isso? Por que não gerar um hash único e enviar pro e-mail do usuário?

Comment: @LINQ como é uma funcionalidade nova pra mim, estou aberto a opiniões, poderia exemplificar como seguir por esse caminho ?

Comment: @DiegoSantos Concordo com o que você disse, porém esse processo de validação de troca de senha por link é novo pra mim! Então ainda estou analisando as melhores rotas pra seguir com boas 'maneiras' para desenvolver essa lógica

Comment: Entendo @IgorCarreiro, e acho que está certo! Bom eu indico esse caminho que falei pq já fiz assim algumas vezes e não é um processo tão honeroso se você já tem um certo conhecimento em banco de dados, principalmente. Exemplos de como gerar a chave, você pode gerar uma no sql server com um select newid(), por exemplo. No C#, pode gerar com um GUID. É bem simples...Mas siga o que achar mais tranquilo pra você! Boa sorte...

Comment: Concordo com o @DiegoSantos, porém eu crio um link que pode ser usado uma vez só, a chave eu gero usando New Guid() e ai só passo pra Base64, simples, único, seguro. no banco coloco esse "key" numa tabela, que tem a referencia do id do usuário, e boa. Marco esse link como acessado, e ai já era, ele fica no banco só pra questão de histórico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondendo à questão inicial:

Utilizando uma função de hash md5, poderia criptografar o id do usuário:

**Função `Md5FromStringUTF8`:**

```
    public static string Md5FromStringUTF8(string input)
    {
        string saida = null;
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            saida = sb.ToString();
        }

        return saida;
    }
```

**Utilização:**

```
BodyContent.Append  ("Link: http://" + link + "/Accounts/RedefinicaoSenha?id=" + Md5FromStringUTF8(CliCodigo) +"");
```

Porém, no seu `controller`, não executaria mais o select pelo id, e sim pelo md5 do id:

```
'Select ... from tabela where CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', id), 2) = [parametro_id]'
```

ou pelo entity:

```
_context.Clientes.Where(x => Md5FromStringUTF8(x.Id) == [parametro_id]).FirstOrDefault();
```

> Entenda [parametro_id] como o parâmetro passado pela Url

---

***Sugestão de melhoria*** com base no comentário de DiegoSantos:

Crie uma classe para as redefinições de senha, e armazene em uma tabela. Quando o usuário fizer uma solicitação para redefinir, você insere um registro, gera o link com a id desse registro, o usuário acessando a Url, verifica se a solicitação é válida, e permite que ele finalize o processo:

```
public class RedefinirSenha
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Clientes Cliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get { return (Data.AddMinutes(10) >= DateTime.Now); } }
    public string Hash { get { return Md5FromStringUTF8(Id.ToString()); } }
}
```

> Considerando que esteja utilizando EntityFramework, e `_context` seja seu `DbContext`

```
public IActionResult ConfirmarEnvio(Clientes objLogin)
{
    RedefinirSenha objRed = new RedefinirSenha()
    {
         Cliente = objLogin,
         Data = DateTime.Now
    };

    _context.RedefinicoesSenha.Add(objRed);
    _context.SaveChanges();


    var link = HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
    Email objEmail = new Email(_config);
    objEmail.CliCodigo = objRed.Id; //Aqui poderia mudar a nomenclatura, já que não será mais codigo do cliente, e também já poderia passar criptografado.

    objEmail.CliEmail = objLogin.CliEmail;
    objEmail.link = link;
    objEmail.EnviarEmail();
    return View("Login");
}
```

> Coloquei a inserção do `RedefinirSenha` na action `ConfirmarEnvio` para exemplificar, acho que poderia colocar essa inserção na action onde é feita a solicitação de senha, e o envio do email recebe como parâmetro esse objeto mantendo a coesão do código.

Por fim, na sua action `RedefinicaoSenha`:

```
public IActionResult RedefinicaoSenha(string id)
{
    RedefinirSenha objRed = _context.RedefinicoesSenha.Where(x=>x.Hash == id && x.IsValid).FirstOrDefault();

    if (objRed != null) 
    {
       //Mudar a senha do cliente com id = objRed.Cliente.id
    }
    else
    {
        //Requisição inválida
    }

    ...
}
```

Espero que ajude, qualquer sugestão de melhoria é bem vinda. =]

Comment: Só um adendo, MD5 herda de HashAlgorithm e precisa do Dispose. `using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()) {}`

Comment: @GabrielColetta obrigado, já atualizei nas funções que uso aqui também =]